# dplyr::recode warning message: "Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible."

Tags: r, dplyr, warnings

I am currently having problems with R. I get really strange error warnings, I have no idea where they come from (even with code that formerly worked). Here just an example (sg1$einsprache is of class numeric):

R-code:

```
table(sg1$einsprache, useNA='always')
sg1$einsprache2<-dplyr::recode(sg1$einsprache, "1='ja';2='nein'")
table(sg1$einsprache2)
```

Output:

```
> table(sg1$einsprache, useNA='always')
   1    2 <NA> 
  92  835    0 
> sg1$einsprache2<-dplyr::recode(sg1$einsprache, "1='ja';2='nein'")
Warning message:
Unreplaced values treated as NA as .x is not compatible. Please specify replacements exhaustively or supply .default 
> table(sg1$einsprache2)

1='ja';2='nein' 
             92
```

What can I try to solve this? Or if I enter `sg1` which is a tibble then I get the warning `Error in loadNamespace(name) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘utf8’`  (there is no package called 'utf8')

Another example:

```
> sg1$einsprache2<-NA
Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'strafe'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'strafe'. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'strafe'. 
4: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'strafe'. 
5: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'gesetz'. 
6: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'gesetz'. 
7: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'gesetz'. 
8: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'gesetz'. 
9: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'gesetz'. 
10: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'gesetz'.
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Could you also add sample data? Errors are also in German(I assume).

Comment: Here I was trying to recode the variable "einsprache" (1/2) into "yes/no". And it worked fine until now...

Comment: Is it a factor recode? Do it manually perhaps?

Comment: I think it is a typo, remove double quotes? `"`: `recode(sg1$einsprache, 1='ja', 2='nein')`

Comment: When I execute your suggestion I get this: Error: unexpected '=' in "recode(sg1$einsprache, 1="
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'strafe'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'strafe'. 
3: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'strafe'. ...

Answer (score 2):

This should solve it: The main point is The quotes ``

```
 df2<-as.data.frame(df2)

  recode(df2$freq1,`4`="Yes",`2`="No",`10`="Yep")
```

Result:

```
recode(df2$freq1,`4`="Yes",`2`="No",`10`="Yep")
[1] "Yes" "No"  "Yep"
```

Data:

```
     freq1 freq2
That     4     5
This     2     3
Tree    10    20
```

Comment: Ah ok, now I got the problem: There's also a function "recode" in the "car"-package. This function was masked by the dplyr-package. But my syntax was right for the car-package.